# Centos 6.3 disk space allocation

Tags: linux, lvm

Apache can use only 50GB, so if my websites go over this amount the server crashes. THis VM has 200GB allocated to it. But I did not set up the volumes correctly. How can I allocate some of the space from lv_home over to lv_root?

```
# df -h
/dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_root
                       50G  5.0G   42G  11% /
tmpfs                 2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M  109M  352M  24% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_home
                  142G  188M  135G   1% /home
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to unmount a filesystem to shrink it.  So, for /home you'll want to be log in as root and `umount /home`.  If it's 'busy'. You may need to stop any processes using files here.

Then, shrink the file system to just below your targeted logical volume size.

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_home 99G
```

Shrink the logical volume to the targeted size.

```
lvreduce -L 100G /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_home
```

Grow the filesystem to the logical volume's capacity.

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_home
```

The reason I do it this so I don't have to do any math and keep the filesystem the size of the container.  A bit lazy, but it works great.

Now, you have free space to grow root.

```
lvextend -L 75G /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_root
```

Don't hesitate to leave some unallocated space since it's easier to grow as needed later.

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron. I will do this today and report back here. Since my VM is a Dev server, I can stop all services anytime. Paul

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it worked great. When I first tried to run:
        `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_root 99G`
it said to "Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_root' first". So I did and then I ran:
        `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_nastgweblls01-lv_home 99G`
I finished the rest of your instructions. And remembered that I need to mount the home drive, so I ran:
        `mount /home`
then ran: df -h and all the new drives sizes were correct! Thanks

Comment: I have a hard time trying to get code formatted and indented in grey using this editor

Comment: Glad to help. Get more markdown help [here](http://serverfault.com/editing-help). Note that comments are subject to restrictions including line-breaks and indents.