# Can't mount home after trying to resize (bad geometry: block count exceeds size of device).

Tags: centos6, mount, disk-volume

This is on a fresh computer (super computer actually).  It got to me with 15T on the home mount and 50G on the root.  I tried allocating 7T to root and resizing (since I'm putting a local yum repo on this machine as it has no internet access nor will it ever).

I tried following the instructions here: [Centos 6.3 disk space allocation](https://serverfault.com/questions/472078/centos-6-3-disk-space-allocation) but something went wrong and the home won't mount again.  Instead I get from dmesg | tail:

```
EXT4-fs (dm-2): bad geometry: block count 4294967295 exceeds size of device (1342177280 blocks)
```

df -h nets this output:

```
Filesystem                                  Size    Used   Avail Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   7.0T  3.6G  6.6T   1%          /
tmpfs                                         190G  216K  190G   1%        /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                                485M   38M   422M  9%    /boot
```

I didn't have any files on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home.  Will simply running mke2fs fix it to be mountable?  What sort of options should I run it with.  I've never resized volumes before or used mke2fs.  I don't want to make this mess worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some researching I gave up and decided to reformat it.

```
mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/Vol_home
```

Good thing I didn't have any data on there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly caused by some trickery of a drive controller possibly in an enclosure - and the problem will likely disappear if reinserted back the way it was - or configured back to the settings as it was when the filesystem was originally created - or it could just be a firmware or utility off-by-one bug (used to be fairly common) - but

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/Vol_home
```

Will fix the superblock (and truncate any data that might have been in the last blocks - which presumably has now been claimed by your controller and won't be made available to the system with the current configuration anyways).