# Centos disk space allocation

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, lvm

My internal server is running out of space. I want allocate some of the space from `lv_home` over to `lv_root`. I have checked the following link: [Centos 6.3 disk space allocation](https://serverfault.com/questions/472078/centos-6-3-disk-space-allocation/631088). It has few commands which I need to run to allocate disk space.

I have a doubt: will I lose my data after running those commands.?

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_sutekar-lv_root
                       50G   48G  822M  99% / 
tmpfs                 3.9G  296K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   47M  413M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_sutekar-lv_home
                      862G  291G  528G  36% /home
```

Comment: Do you know why / (lv_root) is full it may be better to fix that. There is always a chance that data an be lost you will be making sure you have good backups won't you ?

Comment: It contains users data like user images, files and I can't move it to different directory...

Comment: Yes.. I am going to take backup... But should I take a backup of my root directory or home directory or both..?

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose any data if you first resize the filesystem before resizing the logical volume of `/home`. Then the opposite with `/`, resize the logical volume then the filesystem. But don't resize the volume of `/home` before the filesystem or you WILL lose data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you... can you please explain with example..?

Comment: You can check an example here: [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm), there you can see the process of resizing a logical volume, specially on part 4.

Comment: Also, you shoud consider creating new file systems/mount-points for directories such as /var, /tmp...